# How to create an alias from groovy script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

**tl;dr** : I need to create/update aliases from a groovy script called on index creation.

setup : ElasticSearch 1.7.X, [eventhook plugin](https://github.com/codelibs/elasticsearch-eventhook)

situation : I got daily basis indices (automatically created using elastic templates) thats need to be added in 3 aliases : `AliasD`, `AliasD-1` and `AliasD-2`.

what I'm currently doing:

```
indexName = event.indicesCreated().get(0)
dateD = indexName.replace(indexPrefix, "")
date = Date.parse(indexDateFormat, dateJ)
dateD1 = date.clone().next()
dateDp1 = dateP1.format(indexDateFormat)
dateD2 = dateP1.clone().next()
dateDp2 = dateP2.format(indexDateFormat)


def esHost = "http://${esHttpHost}/_aliases"
def json = '{"actions":['+
'{"add":{"index":"'+indexName+'","alias":"'+aliasPrefix+dateDp2+'"}},'+
'{"add":{"index":"'+indexName+'","alias":"'+aliasPrefix+dateDp1+'"}},'+
'{"add":{"index":"'+indexName+'","alias":"'+aliasPrefix+dateD+'"}}]}'

URL es = new URL(esHost);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) es.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");

con.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
os.write(json.getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

Problem: while doing little tests (ie localhost) I can fill the variable `esHttpHost` easily but real world is not that simple... `event` can give me the ES host and port but it's not http port (it's ES one).

Plus I assume there is a better way than rest API to manipulate the cluster as the groovy script is already in ES (`$ESHOME/config/scripts/myWonderfullScript.groovy`)

I'm bounded to ES 1.7.X but open to any other clever solution for hooking to index creation.

Thanks in advance to ES/groovy gurus :)

Comment: what a strange way to build a JSON...

Comment: and yes, you can replace curl with java's native `UrlConnection` or `HttpBuilder` groovy module

Comment: thanks for the `UrlConnection` hint; will edit question with that new code.